# Exigere + a cum prepositional clause?

Tags: cum

Consider this sentence from Seneca's De Brevitate Vitae: "inde Aristotelis cum rerum natura exigentis minime conveniens sapienti viro lis".  The sentence introduces a quotation attributed to Aristotle, but that's not pertinent to my question.  I think: exigentis depends on Aristotelis (both genitive); the sense of exigere here is to deliberate or consider; and "cum rerum natura" says something about what Aristotle was considering, but I can't make sense of "cum."  Translating it temporally would fit the context, but I though cum can be temporal only as part of a clause with a finite verb -- can "cum" be temporal with a participle like exigentis?  Translating cum prepositionally "with the nature of things" sounds awkward in English; we would say "about" or "concerning," I suppose.  But maybe this is a situation in which the meaning of the Latin preposition when used with exigere just does not align exactly with its usual English equivalent.  We might say: "I was struggling with that concept" and maybe the sense of cum is similar here.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: See L & S [exigo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dexigo) II B 7: "To treat, consult, deliberate respecting something, = considerare, deliberare (class. but not in Cic.)" -- examples include *cum eo, cum aliqo, secum* -- would that make sense? (I suppose yes, if Socrates was in an argument with the nature of things.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response; that's further than I got; but I think Kingshorsey has hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxford Latin Dictionary, exigo, 10, e:

> (intr., w. *cum*) to expostulate (with a person)

I suspect that may not have been helpful, so let's consult Merriam-Webster on "expostulate":

> to reason earnestly with a person for purposes of dissuasion or remonstrance

This usage seems related to *exigere* as discussing with someone, but it has acquired a more negative connotation, including disapproval and/or reproach.

Seneca's criticism of Aristotle is that he was complaining about how the world works (*rerum natura*), something a good Stoic philosopher would never do.

Comment: Thanks so much for this response.  It solves the grammatical mystery, and you've helped me appreciate a nuance of Seneca's philosophical position that had escaped me.  My first time posting a question -- the bar has been set high!